# What does "energetically favorable" mean?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, entropy

[Does it mean that the reaction is exothermic?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/82277/119186)

[Or does it mean that $\Delta G<0$?](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What-is-energetically-more-favorable/56b16b0a5cd9e31f6b8b457b/citation/download)

Comment: It means reaction is exothermic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a clear difference between energetically favourable reactions and spontaneous reactions.

Energetically favourable reactions are reactions with $\Delta H <0$ and spontaneous reactions are reactions with $\Delta G <0$.

You might be more familiar with exothermic ($\Delta H <0$) similarly exergonic are reactions with $\Delta G <0$.

Again, I need to prephase that reactions may be exothermic but may not be spontaneous.

For example freezing of ice is exothermic but it cannot happen at $25$ C

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the (true) equilibrium state of a system is maximum entropy state for system+environment. Depending on the way the system and the environment interact macroscopically (for example the system volume or temperature or pressure are held constant) the condition of maximum entropy of system+environment is equivalent to the minimum state for some thermodynamical potential, which depends on the constraints.

An example is when the temperature and volume are fixed, then maximum total entropy is guaranteed if the free energy $F=E-TS$ is minimum. This is usually applicable in solids, where the volume can be assumed to be fixed.

For fixed pressure and temperature, the Gibbs potential will decrease until the system reaches equilibrium.

A reaction (chemical or physical) occurs when a system is not in its maximum entropy state, and from above criteria, we can say that (assuming you meant for fixed $T$ and $P$) the reactions occur in the direction that reduces $G$.